# How to connect to wifi with c++

Tags: cmd, wifi

Is there a command in c++ to connect to a wifi network given name and password of the network? 
There is system() where you can use cmd commands but i am not sure if you can set the exact name and password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890(v=ws.10).aspx)
`Netsh WLAN show profiles` will return a list of configured Wi-Fi networks.
`Netsh WLAN delete profile name="Profile_Name"` will delete a network, where the network SSID is the Profile_Name
`Netsh WLAN add profile` will list all the options of that command for adding networks (profiles)

Comment: can you add the command? links may die over time and future visitors won't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-netsh-commands-for-wi-fi-management-in-windows-8.html
This link can be helpful. 
It also shows how to access passwords on wifi networks (Just in case you've forgotten the password).

Answer (score 0):

To connect, use

```
system('netsh wlan connect xxxxx');
```

Comment: Can you add some details?

Comment: @aloisdg like if I want to connect to a wifi named "Example" I would use
system('netsh wlan connect Example');